# Jumping in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game like geometry dash in pygame. I have everything done except the jumping part. I need it so that when the character is on a square block he can jump up, but cannot double jump in mid air. Right now I have it so that the character is able to jump on the ground but as soon as the character touches jumps on a set of blocks, he starts to bounce up and down and isn't able to jump while gliding on the blocks. Can anyone help please?

```
onblock = False
for i in squares_list:
        if player_rect.bottom <= 560 and player_rect.colliderect(i):
            onblock = True
            player_rect.bottom = i.top + 1
        if player_rect.collidepoint((i.topleft[0], i.topleft[1]+1)):
            print ('Game Over')
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:     # if space is pressed the character jumps
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                print(onblock)
                if onblock or player_rect.bottom == screen.get_rect().bottom  :  # prevents double jumps
                    vel_y = -20   # Makes the character jump up
                    player_rect.y -= 1
    if onblock:
        gravity = 0
        vel_y = 0
        current_angle = 0
    else:
        gravity = 1
        vel_y += gravity

    onblock = False
```

Comment: upon jumping maybe set onblock to True? as in the line after 'player_rect.y -= 1'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're indention is wrong just in this post or in your game, but according to this post, onblock will always be False after every loop. This might be the problem.

The other possible problem might be that you are placing your character 1 pixel above the platform when a collision happens. This means that the next time you check for collision the character will not be resting on the block and therefore the onblock will be False.

The first problem is easily fixed by removing the last line `onblocks = False`. The second problem can be fixed with `player_rect.bottom = i.top` without the +1.

Watch this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0) for more information, especially around [this](https://youtu.be/bMt47wvK6u0?t=1h26m54s) timestamp.